# Add a calendar in Magento frontend

Tags: magento

How can I add a calendar popup in the Magento frontend for a custom form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also define it in a layout file like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code in your indexAction():

```
$this->loadLayout();
$blockCal = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'Mage_Core_Block_Html_Calendar',
    'html_calendar',
    array('template' => 'page/js/calendar.phtml')
);

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($blockCal);
$headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');

$headBlock->addJs('calendar/calendar.js');
$headBlock->addJs('calendar/lang/calendar-en.js');
$headBlock->addJs('calendar/calendar-setup.js');
```